# How do I put more than 2GB file into byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have an algorithm that finds and replaces some hex values of a bin file. But I can't find out how to bypass that 2 GB limit for files that I load into the byte array.

It works just fine when the file size is smaller than 2 GB, but when it is larger, I get an exception

> System.IO.IOException: The file is too long. This operation is currently limited to supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size

So, I store my values in:

```
byte[] find = Array.Empty<byte>(); // assume there is some hex
byte[] replace = Array.Empty<byte>(); // assume there is some hex
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("example.bin");
```

Where find and replace are hex values to be found and replaced, when bytes is array of bytes for my file. Then, to find and replace those values I use the following algorithm:

```
foreach (int index in PatternAt(bytes, find))
{
    for (int i = index, replaceIndex = 0; i < bytes.Length && replaceIndex < replace.Length; i++, replaceIndex++)
    {
        bytes[i] = replace[replaceIndex];
    }

    File.WriteAllBytes("example.bin", bytes);

    Console.WriteLine("Pattern found at offset {0} and replaced.", index);
    continue;
}
```

And the code for `PatternAt` looks like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> PatternAt(byte[] source, byte[] pattern)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            if (source.Skip(i).Take(pattern.Length).SequenceEqual(pattern))
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't. You either deal with the data sequentially via FileStream, or you use something like MemoryMappedFile and unsafe code (perhaps wrapping chunks of the MMF in Span-of-byte, to minimize the unsafe portions)

Comment: When you work with larg amount of data, you do not want to store them into the memory (`File.ReadAllBytes()`) but you want to use streams like [System.IO.FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-7.0)